# Adding specific attribute to form item - jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

Hi there men of the coding realm.

Im trying to add the 'multiple' attribute(?) to a select box via jquery.

essentially I want this:

```
<select tabindex="3" multiple="" style="width:350px;" title="Choose a Country">
```

but not sure how to add the 'multiple' via jquery?

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: want this :                                                                                                                                      <select tabindex="3" multiple="" style="width:350px;" title="Choose a Country">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the attribute you need to give it a value. The actual value doesn't matter. The browser just looks for the presence of the attribute and doesn't take any notice of the value,  but you can't just set it to an empty string. So just do:

```
$("select").attr("multiple", "multiple");
```

To remove the attribute, because you can't set it to an empty string, you use:

```
$("select").removeAttr("multiple");
```

Another similar example is the case of setting the disabled attribute on an input box.

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to add any attribute to dom element.

```
$("select").attr("multiple", "multiple");
```

Comment: thanks. should have worked that out really! assumed attr just targeted

Comment: Kool, make sure you accept the answer if you want your question to be answered going forward.